# Ora2pg - migration Oracle db into postgreSQL without instalation of Oracle

Tags: postgresql, oracle, migration

I have sql file with structure:create table,insert into table, contrains, etc.... This script was generated in oracle, and my job is tranform this script into compatible script for postgreSQL.

Does anyone know if can I use ora2pg without installing oracle? For example only with files .sql or oracle dmp? Or I must allways  first import sql file into Oracle db and then connect to oracle db in ora2pg config file

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[DOCUMENTATION](http://ora2pg.darold.net/documentation.html)

You can use `-i`:

```
-i | --input file : File containing Oracle PL/SQL code to convert with
                    no Oracle database connection initiated.
```

Or set `INPUT_FILE` in `ora2pg.conf`:

> **INPUT_FILE**
>
> This directive did not control the Oracle database
>   connection or unless it purely disable the use of any Oracle database
>   by accepting a file as argument. Set this directive to a file
>   containing PL/SQL Oracle Code like function, procedure or full package
>   body to prevent Ora2Pg from connecting to an Oracle database and just
>   apply his convertion tool to the content of the file. This can be used
>   with the most of export types: TABLE, TRIGGER, PROCEDURE, VIEW,
>   FUNCTION or PACKAGE, etc.

I did not test this though.